# replace class inside jquery html object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to use jquery to apply a function to each html tag with some class inside a html object (imported from a file), but I can't get it to work. I've looked through several other questions on SE but couldn't find a solution to my problem.

The html variable contains much more code in my actual use case, but this

```
html = '<pre class = "classy"> text </pre>'
$(html).find('.classy').each( function (x) { 
    $('<pre class = "classy">' + '<h1>' + x + '<h1>' + '</pre>')
})

'<pre class = "classy"> text </pre>'
```

where the intended output was more like

```
'<pre class = "classy"> <h1> text </h1> </pre>'
```

.replaceWith didn't work either, so I presume I'm doing something conceptually wrong. Any solutions/tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var html = '<pre class = "classy"> text </pre>';
var a = $(html);
a.filter('.classy').each( function (i, x) { 
    $(x).wrapInner('<h1></h1>');
})
```

Here the variable `a` will have the intended content `<pre class = "classy"> <h1> text </h1> </pre>`.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r6Fyz/)

Under the given values it can be even simplified as

```
var a = $(html);
a.each( function (i, x) { 
    $(x).wrapInner('<h1></h1>');
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r6Fyz/1/)

**Note:** If you want contents of `a` as a html string

```
var html = $('<div>').append(a.clone()).html();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r6Fyz/2/)